# How do I divide a date range into years in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe like this:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2018-03-04 | 2020-03-03 |
| b1 | 2019-01-24 | 2021-05-08 |

And I would like an output of this:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2018-03-04 | 2019-03-03 |
| a1 | 2019-03-04 | 2020-03-03 |
| b1 | 2019-01-24 | 2020-01-23 |
| b1 | 2020-01-24 | 2021-01-23 |
| b1 | 2021-01-24 | 2021-05-08 |

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: You might be able to use [`pd.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html?highlight=date_range#pandas.date_range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def split_date_range(row):
    start, end = row[['start', 'end']]
    dates = []

    s = start
    while True:
        e = s + pd.DateOffset(years=1) - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        if e < end:
            dates.append((s, e))
            s = e + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            dates.append((s, end))
            break
    return dates

tmp = df.set_index('id').apply(split_date_range, axis=1).explode()
result = pd.DataFrame([ 
    [id_, *timerange] for id_, timerange in tmp.iteritems()
], columns=['id', 'start', 'end'])
```

The code uses `id_` to avoid collision with the `id()` built-in function.

Comment: thank you! This solution worked great!!